# Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-prism-component'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, module

I am using Vue 3 (Composition Api), Vite and Typescript. I got missing module of vue-prism-component.

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import 'prismjs'
import 'prismjs/themes/prism-tomorrow.css'
import Prism from 'vue-prism-component'

</script>

Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-prism-component'. '/Users/haotranhuynhhuy/Desktop/Vuejs/jarvis 2.0/node_modules/vue-prism-component/dist/vue-prism-component.common.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/vue-prism-component` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-prism-component';`

3 import Prism from 'vue-prism-component'
```

**Can not install library @types/vue-prism-component because it not exist.**

npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fvue-prism-component - Not found

npm ERR! 404  '@types/vue-prism-component@*' is not in this registry.

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/haotranhuynhhuy/.npm/_logs/2022-12-16T07_22_15_496Z-debug-0.log

Try to declear file for module 'vue-prism-component'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add declare module 'vue-prism-component' in shims.d.ts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).